# Как подключать удаленные скрипты Yii2

Tags: yii2

Есть скрипт

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Как его подключить в фреймворке Yii2

Comment: Можете в используемом css первой строкой прописать @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic,latin-ext");

Comment: @Visman к сожалению не помогло

Comment: Тут парсер ссылку съел. Надо в скобках в кавычках прописать ссылку, которая у вас прописана в href.

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь подключить не скрипты, а CSS-стили шрифта.

В нужном View добавляем код

```
$this->registerCssFile('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic,latin-ext');
```

Если этот шрифт используется на всех страницах сайта, то лучше добавить URL этих стилей в AppAsset в раздел $css. Напрмер:

```
public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic,latin-ext',
    ];
```

P.S: указывать протокол (http) в URL не советую, браузеры сами будут использовать тот протокол, по которому пользователь подключился к сайту. Если начнете использовать HTTPS, браузеры будут ругаться на загрузку небезопасного контента при безопасном соединении